# Trying to get reference to ExtJS Grid from toolbar

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a Grid..

And I have a toolbar..

```
Ext.define('js.grid.PackageGrid', {

    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

    tbar: [{
         GridUtils.getSearchTextField(myGridReferenceHere)
    }]

}
```

I need to get a reference to the defining Grid. I am not sure this is possible. Is it possible?

- I tried **this**, but that gave me some other funny global object.
- I tried using a variable and passing that in but that just ended up being an undefined object *(Eg: var ref = Ext.define('js.grid.PackageGrid') )*

**EDIT FROM ORIGINAL POSTER:**

I ended up doing it like this: The text field is defined in the grid, and only the search action is delegated to another method.

tbar: [{

```
        xtype: 'textfield', enableKeyEvents: true, listeners: {
            keyup: function (string) {

                var grid = this.up();

                gridUtils.getSearchAction(tablestore, string, grid)
            }
        }
```

}]

Comment: Note that the question demonstrates a fairly fundamental misunderstanding of the class system. `Ext.define` creates a class type (not instance). You can't get a grid reference there, because it doesn't exist, only the type exists.

Comment: yes, I am still very new to ExtJS :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
tbar: [{
     GridUtils.getSearchTextField(this.up())
}]
```

http://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Toolbar-method-up

Comment: this worked for me. I had to first define my GUI component (ie textField), and then have the listeners being called at runtime instead.

Comment: I downvoted this. While the mention of `up` led the OP in the right direction, this answer absolutely won't work. `this` will not refer to anything useful at this point because it's at class definition time. Somewhat surprised it was accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible during the define time. You execute the above method at the time when neither grid nor toolbar exists. You can get the reference during `initComponent` execution of either grid or toolbar but not at the define time.

For more info see:

- [Ext/Touch Component Life Cycle](http://extjs.eu/ext-touch-component-life-cycle/)
- [Ext Application Startup Sequence](http://extjs.eu/ext-application-startup-sequence/)

Comment: yes, i moved out the textfield from define time, and just added a callback. With this.up() I could get the grid :)